# Skrollr doesn't animate last div at the right place

Tags: javascript, html, skrollr

I am using Skrollr to make some nice parallax effects on a website I'm making.
The two first divs are working fine, but at the bottom Skrollr isn't working correctly.

I can see that it makes something when I'm at the top of the site, so when I'm scrolling down the div is already at the bottom.

Can anyone please take a look and see what I'm missing here?
I will soon probably start pulling my hair :)

The link is http://crap.futuredev.se/gd/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: pls you can more explain your problem or can you send screenshot what is your problem ? thx (i tested your link in chrome and working fine i guess)

Comment: I probably used the data-tags wrong, I rewrote alot this morning and now it's working. The bottom .kontakt was positioned correctly when I was at the top of the whole document not relative to the parent #kontakt. Now I'm using data-anchor-target and data-top-bottom to position it. Seems to be working. Thank you for taking your time!